# MultiTimeFrame Indicator BackTesting mql4

Tags: indicator, trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

before posting any code I would like to understand if it is possible to backtest a <kbd>Custom Indicator</kbd>, for a <kbd>MetaTrader4 Terminal</kbd>, based on a multi time frame strategy.

I have looked on `mql5` forum, but I could not find any clear indications or approach to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>...before posting any answer I would like to understand, what do you consider a multi-time frame strategy in custom indicator context.</sub>*

### How to make the step forward?

Select your own way - **The Approach**

In any case,
 one can use function calls aimed to retrieve values, collected from a perspective of a different time-frame, with a use of proper indication of 
**`{ PERIOD_M1 | .. | PERIOD_H1 | PERIOD_H4 | .. }`**
 in the function call protocol,

**or**

one can create and maintain one's own virtual super-framing / sub-framing independently of the current graph's "*own*" time-frame.

```
double v30SEC_O[], v30SEC_H[], v30SEC_L[], v30SEC_C[],
       vM1_O[   ], vM1_H[   ], vM1_L[   ], vM1_C[   ],
       vM3_O[   ], vM3_H[   ], vM3_L[   ], vM3_C[   ],
       vH7_O[   ], vH7_H[   ], vH7_L[   ], vH7_C[   ];    // vTF as needed

bool   v30SEC_newBarEVENT = False,
       vM1_newBarEVENT    = False,
       vM3_newBarEVENT    = False,
       vH7_newBarEVENT    = False;

void   aNewBarEventMONITOR(){ ...
       static int  v30SEC_Bars  = EMPTY,
                   vM1_Bars     = EMPTY,
                   vM3_Bars     = EMPTY,
                   vH7_Bars     = EMPTY;

    // check aNewBarEVENT:

    // update state-vars:

}
```

### Does it work in spite of many posts on failed MTF [`StrategyTester`] results?

In each of cases posted above, one may use the other one to check and proof the correctness of the outputs.

Yes, unit-tests are a **good** safety belts **habit** in this domain.

The recent "***new***"-`MQL4.56789+` shifts and frequent interim compiler ( syntax ) live-updates ( you get a new Help to notice them ) make unit-testing a must-do part of the pre-release testing + production code maintenance.

Comment: It is a Custom Indicator that collects data from Period_M1, M5, M15 and returns a signal to open a new trade. it works in forward test, meaning on a demo account it does what is meant for, but I would like to backtest in order to optimize the entry points.

Comment: Clear, Fabio, and where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I am backtesting I do not get the same entries and/or exits as in the manual test. I have been reading that is a complicated issues backtesting strategies that use MTF indicators, but I could not find either an example or any literature explaining how and what to do.
The indicator is coded following the guidelines give at this link [link](http://www.forexfactory.com/showthread.php?p=6413839)
but even in forward test (demo/live) it is not very precise.

Comment: Have you realised, Fabio, that most of the referred FF-thread is more than 3 years old, i.e., before "new"-MQL4.56789 came in? **Anyway, the solution is doable,** if you take properly the extra care, which is needed. Normally I prefer to use and maintain virtualTimeFrame handlers and keep all logic in EA, so as to avoid single-thread overloads on Custom Indicator engine + this allows easy external testing / support from ( messaging sockets interconnected ) python / numpy modules.

Comment: I did see that the mql4 posts were old, but I was going to lose anything in trying.
so you are saying to code the indicator as a function in the EA?

Comment: also could you provide an example virtualTimeFrame implementation, please?

Comment: **Yes**, I am. Having trivially put indicator calculations into EA you gain better portability. While there are still issues that remain ( i.e. no direct  access to deeper "history" once started in Strategy Tester. Workaround exist ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90730/discussion-between-fabio-geraci-and-user3666197).